# How do I reduce a 10GB *c:\pagefile.sys* and 10GB *c:\hiberfil.sys* on a 50GB boot partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, multi-boot, pagefile

I've got a preinstalled Win10, which I dual booted with win81. I extended both, after which the Win81 partition didn't boot anymore. (Maybe it *moved* too, IDK). I finally got it to boot, but now there's a 10GB **c:\pagefile.sys** and 10GB **c:\hiberfil.sys** on a 50GB boot partition.

What would happen if I dual booted into Win10, and simply deleted those Win81 **c:\pagefile.sys** and 10GB **c:\hiberfil.sys**? Because now 20G of disk-space is just wasted.

Failing that, how do I reduce the first partition (Win10) 'formally' in the correct manner, using Gparted and a Win81 installation USB? I wanna do that because it got whacked up and i need to replace it.

Comment: Disable hibernate and disable your page file (but doing that wouldn't have a severe effect on performance)

Comment: @Ramhound means it **would** have a severe effect on performance.

Comment: If the computer has 16GB or more RAM disabling or reducing the pagefile to something like 1GB or 500MB would probably work. Reducing is safer than disabling it altogether, though.